# How to print from a mobile app using a webview control?

Tags: android, asp.net, eclipse, pdf, webview

Sorry in advance, because it may be a duplicate thread. But try to I search so much, and also I find some solutions also, but I am unable to reach my goal using that solution.

I try to create a simple android mobile app. Using Eclips, I just use WebView control and target that control to a mobile web page (by using loadUrl) which is asp .net page (mobile web form). But I fail to call print method from web page.

Then I try to create a pdf and try to open/download. I successfully create the pdf file. But fail to open that file in separate window (adobe reader) and also I am unable to download that file in device.

Please give some solution to open pdf in separate window (outside mobile app) or download the pdf file from server to local device.

Thanks in advance.

**What I have tried:**

```
//On my mobile app I use: 
WebView wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser()); String url = "http://example.com/testprint.aspx"; 
wv1.loadUrl(url);

//On testprint.aspx I use: 
<html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; > <body> 
<mobile:Form id="Form1" runat="server"> 
<mobile:Command ID="Command1" Runat="server" OnClick="Command1_Click">Command</mobile:Command> 
</mobile:Form> </body> </html>

//On testprint.aspx.cs I use: 
string FilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MyPDF\\test.pdf";
//I write a method here to create pdf file 
/*.......*/ 
//After that I write this code for open that file (which I create above)
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf"); 
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath); 
Response.End();


//I also try to use below method also to download the file
string FilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MyPDF\\test.pdf";
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(_Path));

const int _bufferLength = 10000;
byte[] _buffer = new Byte[_bufferLength];
int _length = 0;
Stream _download = null;
try
{
    _download = new FileStream(_Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    do
    {
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {
            _length = _download.Read(_buffer, 0, _bufferLength);
            Response.OutputStream.Write(_buffer, 0, _length);
            _buffer = new Byte[_bufferLength];
        }
        else
        {
            _length = -1;
        }
    }
    while (_length > 0);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
finally
{
    if (_download != null) _download.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bernoulli Gate, for title modification. If there is no direct print method, please give some idea to open pdf file in client's pdf viewer application (adobe reader or else) not in my app, or download pdf file from server to client's mobile device.

Comment: Unclear. Link the PDF. It will give the user a choice to open it directly or to download it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use a button on the webpage (which was target on mobile app's webview's url), and onclick event I used above two method (alternately) to open/download the pdf file. But nothing happen. But when I open that webpage in browser it working fine.

Comment: `use a button on the webpage (which was target on mobile app's webview's url), and onclick event I used above two method (alternately) to open/download the pdf file.` Sounds **terrible**. You should point your mobile to the remote URL, not the other way.

Comment: Yes, I done that (and I think I am unable to express what I did and what I want). I point my app to remote url. On that web page there is a button and I use above code (there is two method, I try one by one) to open the file. When I using my app and clicking button, nothing happening, but when I typing that url on browser it is working (downloading that file).

Comment: Still too complicate. Why can't you simply have a web page showing a **link** (`<a href="URL of your pdf">Some text here</a>`)?

Comment: Thank you @BernoulliGate for your help. I try to build very simple mobile app and build using Eclips.

On my mobile app I use:

WebView  wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv1.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
String url = "http://...../testprint.aspx";          
wv1.loadUrl(url);

Comment: On testprint.aspx I use:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
  <mobile:Form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <mobile:Command ID="Command1" Runat="server" OnClick="Command1_Click">Command</mobile:Command>
  </mobile:Form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: On testprint.aspx.cs I use:
string FilePath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\MyPDF\\test.pdf";
//I write a method here to create pdf file
//.....

//After that I write this code for open that file (which I create above)
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
Response.End();

Comment: Don't put code in comments. You should edit your question, instead.